# Using logical operands in javascript with objects

Tags: javascript

I came across the use of the logical operand `&&` with objects however would like to know whether expressions are evaluated in the manner below only when dealing with objects.

**Code Sample**

```
var sampleObject = {
            size: 10, 
            shoe: {
                make: "nike",
                model: "air jordon"
            },
            color: "red"
            }

    console.log(sampleObject.size && sampleObject.shoe.model);
```

The out of `console.log(sampleObject.size && sampleObject.shoe.model);` returns `air jordon`. My understanding is that because the first condition i.e. `sampleObject.size` evaluated to true and isn't `falsely` it returns the value contained in the object `sampleObbject.shoe.model`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `||` and `&&` operators run from left to right. In the case of `||`, the first truthy value is returned. For `&&`, it's the first falsy value. In both cases, the last one is returned if no suitable return value is found.

So, in this case, the fact that it returned a truthy value for the expression means that both `sampleObject.size` and `sampleObject.show.model` are truthy values.

Comment: So the same principle and rule applies i.e. left to right regardless of whether it is an object, if else statements, etc?

Comment: That is correct. Execution stops as soon as the chain can return something, so in particular it is useful to test if an object property exists before getting a sub-property.

Comment: The above is incorrect. For the `&&` operator, **either** the value of the first "falsey" expression is returned **or** the value of the last expression if all preceding expressions evaluate to true. The value of `sampleObject.shoe.model` is returned because it's the last expression and all preceding expressions evaluate to true. It doesn't matter if it evaluates to true or false.

Comment: RobG - So if the key/property `size` was say `0`, the value returned would be `0`?

Comment: @RobG - If you provide an answer, be happy to award it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey—Yes, if the value of the first expression converts to false, then that is the value returned. See [ECMA–262 §11.11 Binary Logical Operators](http://es5.github.com/#x11.11). Note that `The value produced by a && or || operator is not necessarily of type Boolean. The value produced will always be the value of one of the two operand expressions.`

Comment: @RobG That's what I said: "the last value is returned if no suitable [ie. truthy/falsy based on the operator] return value is found"

Comment: @Kolink—possibly semantics, but to me your statement (`the fact that it returned a truthy value for the expression means that both sampleObject.size and sampleObject.show.model are truthy values`) is half correct. If the left expression is true, the value of the right expression is returned regardless of whether it's true or not. The fact that the right hand expression converts to true is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

The Javascript `&&` operator first evaluates its left operand.  If it's a falsey value, it is the value of the entire expression.  If it's a truthy value, then the right operand is evaluated, and it is returned.

Zeros, empty strings, undefined, and false are all falsey values.  Your sampleObject.size value is 10, a truthy value, so the right operand is evaluated and used as the value of the entire expression.

Note that none of this depends on the values being objects.

Comment: @Ned Batchelder - Is it always evaluated from left to right or is this limited to objects only?

Comment: It's always left to right.  I'm not sure where you got the idea that objects make anything different here.  As I said above, nothing about this is because you are using objects.